# Part of UIViewController's view offscreen when navigation bar visible

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

`BaseViewController : UINavigationController` contains common basic behavior (like handling virtual keyboard, etc); and is a parent class to all view controllers in the app.

Some of those view controllers have navigation bar hidden, others don't. In case of visible nav. bar, the view controller's self.view is shifted down by the hight of the navigation bar; so i get 44 pixels off screen. I'm probably missing something obvious. Nonetheless, i'd like to ask about a elegant way to handle this situation. Thanks.

Comment: What is the view hierarchy of this controller?

Comment: @A'saDickens i'm talking about viewController's self.view; not a subview of it.

Comment: so hypothetically speaking if your self.view had a tableView with in the self.view, and the tabelView and lets say you were using autoresizing mask, and the storyboard was set up for the 4 inch displays and you were running it on the 3.5 inch and the tableView didn't have the correct mask to resize then it would appear that the tableView is shifted down because it would not move when the self.view was resized

Comment: @A'saDickens okay, this is one hypothetical option. Another one would be, if i'd be adding programmatically [self.view addSubview:otherView] at the bottom of self.view, that otherView will be hidden fully or partially at bottom. So i want to handle this situation in the base class.

Comment: alright, that is weird behavior indeed, are you using auto layout ? and is this controller allocated in code or via storyboard?

Comment: @A'saDickens no autolayout. Never worked for me (in my opinion it brings complications instead of simplicity - in xcode 5 a different story however). And no storyboard either. Although the issue seems pretty logical - if you got a nav bar at the top, the view will be shifted down. The only solution i see now is to add a subview and work with that instead of self.view

Comment: When you call the method setNavigationBarHidden: it dynamically resizes the scene's view to accommodate for the navigation bar, and when you push/pop the screens should be the right height, are you pushing/popping or are you adding the view of one controller to the other controller, such as [viewController1.view addSubview:viewController2.view];